# How to add --restart='always' to container already created

Tags: docker

I've created a container and I've forgot to set the --restart='always' when I created it.

Is it possible to modify this option for a container already created? I know I can created a new one but that would be useful because it had happened to me several times...

Answer (score 2):

`docker update` now allows to change configuration of running container, including restart policy - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/